# When does the name mangling occur when using double underscores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__test = "cats"
        print(self.__test)

    def __example(self):
        print("Hello World")

x = Test()
print(x.__dict__)
```

With the code I wrote above, the print statement will show to access the variable `test`, I will need to write `_Test__test`, however as shown I can print the variable if I call it directly afterwards within the `__init__` method. So my question is, if I can access it directly after it has been declared by its name i.e `self.__test`, at which point does it become mangled?

Comment: It seems simple enough - every time you try to access a name from within the class, it's mangled before lookup. That's when you create it as well as when you use it.

Comment: Why isn't it mangled when typing print(self.__test) in line 5?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes accessed via `.__` are mangled *anywhere in the class body* (But an inner class declaration would get to it first.).

Think of it as *syntactic sugar.*

In the context of the `Test` class body, `self.__test` is an *alias* to the mangled name `self._Test__test`; in context, they mean *exactly the same thing*.

A demonstration would make this clearer. First, some helper classes.

```
class PrintAttrAccess:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print(name)

class Empty: pass
```

Now for the demonstration:

```
class Test:
    print('IN TEST BODY')
    (lambda: PrintAttrAccess().__in_lambda)()  # Anywhere in the class body works.
    classfoo = Empty()
    classfoo.__foo = 'foo'
    print("Same thing?", classfoo.__foo is classfoo._Test__foo)
    print("vars() of classfoo:", vars(classfoo))

    class Inner:
        print('IN INNER')
        PrintAccess().__inner

    def __init__(self):
        print('IN INIT')
        print("Who am I?", self)
        self.__test = "cats"
        print(self._Test__test)  # It's ALREADY MANGLED!
        # This line means exactly the same as the one above.
        print(self.__test)
        localfoo = Empty()
        localfoo.__spam = 'spam' # "self" isn't special.
        print("vars() of localfoo:", vars(localfoo))


def outside_method(self):
    print('OUTSIDE BODY')
    print("Who am I?", self)
    self.__test = "dogs"
    print(self._Test__test)
    print(self.__test)  # Sugar doesn't apply outside of class body.

Test.outside_method = outside_method  # Add a new method to Test class.

Test().outside_method()  # init and call as method.
```

The output is:

```
IN TEST BODY
_Test__in_lambda
Same thing? True
vars() of classfoo: {'_Test__foo': 'foo'}
IN INNER
_Inner__inner
IN INIT
Who am I? <__main__.Test object at 0x000001CCF3048978>
cats
cats
vars() of localfoo: {'_Test__spam': 'spam'}
OUTSIDE BODY
Who am I? <__main__.Test object at 0x000001CCF3048978>
cats
dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I can access it directly after it has been declared by its name i.e `self.__test`, at which point does it become mangled?

It becomes mangled when you reference it from **outside** the class.

Your line 5, `print(self.__test)` isn't mangled because you're referencing it from *inside* the class. It's only mangled once you refer to it from outside the class. Thus, you would call

```
print(x._Test__test)
```

Note that, you could also use `self._Test__test` within your class.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__test = "cats"

    def get(self):
        return self._Test__test

x = Test()
print(x.get())                      ##  cats
```

I think this article explains it pretty well: [*The Meaning of Underscores in Python*](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python).